# how to estimate yaw of object in stereo vision

Tags: 3d, pose

If I can obtain the R/L face images by stereo cameras and get two eyes' position, Is there any way to estimate the theta(red) shown in the following figure? Please give me some advice, Thanks for your help!

[Stereo Vision for angle estimation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m9rV.png)

We may estimate the 3D position of the object (middle of eyes), to get relative position between middle of Cams and object, and then further calculate theta. But Is any simple / direct way to get the theta without calculate 3D positions of objects?